# Comparing Two Arrays with Array.filter and Pushing to New Arrays Based on Common Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use `array.filter()` to compare two arrays and separate out values that the two arrays have in common, based on a certain property (id), vs. values they don't have in common. The common ids I want to push to a new array (recordsToUpdate). And I want to push the remaining elements from `arr2` to a new array (recordsToInsert).

What I've tried is not working. How can I rework this to get the results I wanted? - (which in the example here should be one array of 1 common element `{id: 3}`, and another array of the remaining elements from `arr2`):

```
const arr1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
const arr2 = [{id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}];

let recordsToUpdate = [];
let recordsToInsert = [];

recordsToUpdate = arr1.filter(e => (arr1.id === arr2.id));
recordsToInsert = ?

console.log('recordsToUpdate: ', recordsToUpdate);
console.log('recordsToInsert: ', recordsToInsert);
```

The desired result should be:

```
recordsToUpdate = [{id: 3}];
recordsToInsert = [{id: 4}, {id: 5}];
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Okay, I have added the desired result. There is one overlapping value between the two arrays. Updated with correct info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, which uses [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to test for whether an object exists in `arr2` with a given `id`:

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
const arr2 = [{id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}];

const recordsToUpdate = arr1.filter(e => arr2.find(obj => obj.id === e.id) !== undefined);
const recordsToInsert = arr1.filter(e => arr2.find(obj => obj.id === e.id) === undefined);

console.log('recordsToUpdate: ', recordsToUpdate);
console.log('recordsToInsert: ', recordsToInsert);
```

Comment: I see, you have to delineate obj to target the property. Makes sense. Many thanks, @Robin.

Answer (score 3):

Update to Robin post using `some` instead of `find`. It is just other way around.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
const arr2 = [{id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}];

const recordsToUpdate = arr1.filter(e => arr2.some(obj => obj.id === e.id));
const recordsToInsert = arr2.filter(e => !arr1.some(obj => obj.id === e.id));

console.log('recordsToUpdate: ', recordsToUpdate);
console.log('recordsToInsert: ', recordsToInsert);
```

Comment: Ha, thanks - I was fairly sure there must be some ES6 array method to make this simpler but for some reason didn't remember `some`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after... I added values to show the replacement. If you are doing any kind of state management, be careful as I am directly mutating the current array.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, v: "a" },
  { id: 2, v: "b" },
  { id: 3, v: "old" }
];
const arr2 = [
  { id: 3, v: "new" },
  { id: 4, v: "e" },
  { id: 5, v: "f" }
];

function updateRecords(currentArray, updatesArray) {
  const currentIds = currentArray.map(item => item.id);

  updatesArray.forEach(updateItem =>
    currentIds.includes(updateItem.id)
      ? (currentArray[
          currentIds.findIndex(id => id === updateItem.id)
        ] = updateItem)
      : currentArray.push(updateItem)
  );

  return currentArray;
}

console.log(updateRecords(arr1, arr2))
```

This now gives the option below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "v": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "v": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "v": "new"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "v": "e"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "v": "f"
  }
]
```

Putting it in a function is also something you likely want to do as you will likely use this multiple places in your code.